# Cannot import JSON to Parse backend

Tags: json, parse-platform

So I am trying to create a class in the Parse backend by importing a JSON file but am unable to do so.

I get the error:

`Row 1 is invalid: invalid field name : 15`

My JSON looks like the following:

```
{
"results":[
{

"9": [ {"subject":"Operating Systems","room":"L21"} ],
"10": [ {"subject":"Microprocessors","room":"L21"} ],
"11": [ {"subject":"Chemistry","room":"L11"} ],
"12": [ {"subject":"Mathematics","room":"L16"} ],
"14": [ {"subject":"Chemistry Lab (G1)","room":""} ],
"15": [ {"subject":"Chemistry Lab (G1)","room":""} ],
"16": [ {"subject":"Chemistry Lab (G1)","room":""} ]
}

]

}
```

I checked it on JSONlint, and my JSON syntax is perfectly valid.

Any help where I am wrong?

Comment: Seems like duplicate `subject` for elements `14`, `15` and `16`. Though, this needs more info for debugging.

Comment: I tried changing it but now I get the same error but 12 instead of 15